# Ruby serialization data structure

Tags: ruby, json, serialization

I am trying to serialize a complex JSON structure from Ruby.  I'm not using Rails, but am new enough at Ruby that I'm not sure if that matters here. 
The API on the other end is  expecting something like this

```
{ "command" : {
   "param" : { "field" : "val", "otherField":"otherVal" },
   "param" : { "field" : "val", "otherField":"otherVal" },
   "param" : { "field" : "val", "otherField":"otherVal" }
    }
}
```

What kind of ruby object does command hold, before serialization? It isn't an array, because there would be another level of square brackets (see example below).  And I'm new to ruby, but don't think you can have more than one object with the same name in a hash, either.

Backstory: Because hashes and arrays otherwise serialize to json so nicely in Ruby, I was expecting something like this:

```
Ary = Array.new
Ary.push (param.new)
Ary.push (param.new)
Ary.push (param.new)
wrappedCmd = { "command" => Ary }
Oj.dump(wrappedCmd)
```

But this produces:

```
{ "command" : [
   "param" : { "field" : "val", "otherField":"otherVal" },
   "param" : { "field" : "val", "otherField":"otherVal" },
   "param" : { "field" : "val", "otherField":"otherVal" }
    ]
}
```

I've confirmed that the first format is what is expected, as a manually-constructed serialization goes through, while the second produces invalid format errors.

Comment: That is *semantically invalid* JSON if all the keys are literally "param" - the API is broken if that is what it wants. It is not possible for a key to be duplicated in a Map (such as a JSON Object or a Ruby Hash). Make sure that said invalid JSON is indeed "correct". (And no proper JSON library will allow for emitting such broken markup.)

Comment: Hmm. OK. Don't have any control over the API end, and it accepted the first format.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that the first one contains a hash, and the second one contains an array. So you should do something like this instead:

```
cmd = {}
cmd['param1'] = Param.new
cmd['param2'] = Param.new
cmd['param3'] = Param.new
Oj.dump("command" => cmd)
```

Indeed, hashes can't have duplicate key names. It sounds like your API isn't using proper JSON?

Comment: But wouldn't this produce:{ "command":
        param1: stuff,
        param2: stuff,
        param3: stuff
    }

Comment: Of course not. At least, not with a standard JSON serialiser.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happens if you try to parse that initial JSON string:

```
require 'json'

foo = JSON['{ "command" : {
   "param" : { "field" : "val", "otherField":"otherVal" },
   "param" : { "field" : "val", "otherField":"otherVal" },
   "param" : { "field" : "val", "otherField":"otherVal" }
    }
}']

foo # => {"command"=>{"param"=>{"field"=>"val", "otherField"=>"otherVal"}}}
```

So, we know that's not valid. I suspect the JSON is merely a poorly written example. Since it makes no sense to keep sending the same `"param"`, those should be different parameter names.

Regarding your code: It isn't idiomatic Ruby.

```
Ary = Array.new
Ary.push (param.new)
Ary.push (param.new)
Ary.push (param.new)
wrappedCmd = { "command" => Ary }
```

We'd write it like:

```
ary = []
ary << param.new
ary << param.new
ary << param.new
wrapped_cmd = { "command" => ary }
```

Or even more simply:

```
ary = [
  param.new,
  param.new,
  param.new,
]
wrapped_cmd = { "command" => ary }
```

Or even:

```
wrapped_cmd = { 
  "command" => [
      param.new,
      param.new,
      param.new,
  ] 
}
```

- Constants start with a capital letter, variables start with lower-cased letters, so use `ary` instead of `Ary`.
- Typically we use `[]` to initialize an empty array rather than `Array.new`. It's a readability thing.
- Typically we use `<<` to append elements onto arrays. Again, it's a readability thing.
- variables in Ruby are written in snake_case, not camelCase, for readability again. It's easier_to_read_snake_case thanItIsToReadCamelCase.

Comment: I think the root of the problem is that what this API accepts isn't proper JSON. "param" is the toy problem, but it is indeed expecting the same field repeated 3 times. Looks like someone took an old XML format and tried turning it into json, in which case <cmd> <param> stuff</param><param>second one</param></cmd> is both normal and reasonable.

Comment: Since we have absolutely NO idea what API the OP is talking about, we're totally shooting in the dark and everything is speculation.

Comment: Proprietary call to an external (non-Ruby) system expecting a string. String is documented as json text that looks like the original post, w/ a bunch of duplicated params and missing some array brackets.  Being new to ruby, I thought this was some json construct I'd not encountered before. Not shooting in the dark, constraining answer to question asked.